# How to clear screen after clicking button?

Tags: python, python-3.x, button, pygame

I'm attempting to build a menu based program where if I click on a button, it corresponds to a function; and it will carry out certain conditions. However, I am unable to get the button itself working. I wish to have it so that when I click on the button, the screen fills with another colour and so that I am able to have another screen with whatever function it has clicked on. I've added my code below; any help is so greatly appreciated!

This is the button that I have been having trouble with:

```
def arrayIntro():
intro = True
while intro:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mousePosition = pygame.mouse.get_pos()                             

    screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)

    textChoice = pygame.font.SysFont('americantypewriter', 20)

    mousePosition = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    mouseClick = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

#Top Row Draw Rects        

    if 50+250 > mousePosition[0] > 50 and 50 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 50:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (50, 50, 250, 100))
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (50, 50, 250, 100))

    enterInt = textChoice.render("enterInt", True, NAVYBLUE)
    screen.blit(enterInt, (135, 90))

    if mouseClick[0] ==1:
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
```

However if necessary, here is all of my code:

```
 #Import the necessary modules
import pygame
import sys
import os

#Initialize pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the size for the surface (screen)
screenSize = (900,750)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenSize),0)

# Set the caption for the screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Array")

#Define Colours
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
GRAY = (128, 128, 128)
MAROON = (128, 0, 0)
NAVYBLUE = (0, 0, 128)
OLIVE = (128, 128, 0)
PURPLE = (128, 0, 128)
TEAL = (0,128,128)
PINK = (226,132,164)
MUTEDBLUE = (155,182,203)
PLUM = (221,160,221)   


def selectedFirst():
    runFirst = True

    while runFirst:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
        pygame.display.update()

def enterInt():
    runFirst = True

    while runFirst:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
        pygame.display.update()

def display():
    runSecond = True

    while runFirst:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
        pygame.display.update()

def countInt():
    runFirst = True

    while runFirst:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
        pygame.display.update()

def displayReverse():

    runFirst = True
    while runFirst:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
        pygame.display.update()

def sumInt():
    runFirst = True

    while runFirst:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
        pygame.display.update()

def average():
    runFirst = True
    while runFirst:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
        pygame.display.update()

def findMaxORfindMin():
    runFirst = True
    while runFirst:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
        pygame.display.update()

def search():
    runFirst = True
    while runFirst:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
        pygame.display.update()

def writeToText():
    runFirst = True
    while runFirst:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
        pygame.display.update()

def fillFromText():
    runFirst = True
    while runFirst:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
        pygame.display.update()

def searchReplace():
    runFirst = True
    while runFirst:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
        pygame.display.update()

def shuffleArray():
    runFirst = True
    while runFirst:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
        pygame.display.update()

def wordCount():
    runFirst = True
    while runFirst:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
        pygame.display.update()

def arrayIntro():
    buttonenterInt = pygame.Rect(50, 50, 250, 100)
    buttondisplay =pygame.Rect(325, 50, 250, 100)
    buttoncountInt = pygame.Rect(600, 50, 250, 100)

    buttondisplayReverse = pygame.Rect(50, 250, 250, 100)
    buttonsumInt = pygame.Rect(325, 250, 250, 100)
    buttonaverage = pygame.Rect(600, 250, 250, 100)

    buttonfindMaxORfindMin = pygame.Rect(50, 450, 250, 100)
    buttonsearch = pygame.Rect(325, 450, 250, 100)
    buttonwriteToText= pygame.Rect(600, 450, 250, 100)

    buttonfillFromText =pygame.Rect(50, 640, 250, 100)
    buttonsearchReplace = pygame.Rect(325, 640, 250, 100)
    buttonwordCount = pygame.Rect(600, 640, 250, 100)

    intro = True
    while intro:
        mousePosition = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
        textChoice = pygame.font.SysFont('americantypewriter', 20)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1):
                clicked = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

                if buttonenterInt.collidepoint(clicked):
                    selectedFirst()

                elif buttondisplay.collidepoint(clicked):
                    display()

                elif buttoncountInt.collidepoint(clicked):
                    countInt()

                elif buttondisplayReverse.collidepoint(clicked):
                    displayReverse()

                elif buttonsumInt.collidepoint(clicked):
                    sumInt()

                elif buttonaverage.collidepoint(clicked):
                    average()

                elif buttonfindMaxORfindMin.collidepoint(clicked):
                    findMaxORfindMin()

                elif buttonsearch.collidepoint(clicked):
                    search()

                elif buttonwriteToText.collidepoint(clicked):
                    writeToText()

                elif buttonfillFromText.collidepoint(clicked):
                    fillFromText()

                elif buttonsearchReplace.collidepoint(clicked):
                    searchReplace()

                elif buttonshuffleArray.collidepoint(clicked):
                    shuffleArray()

                elif buttonwordCount.collidepoint(clicked):
                    wordCount() 
#########################################################################################
#Top Row Draw Rects
        if 50+250 > mousePosition[0] > 50 and 50 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 50:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (50, 50, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (50, 50, 250, 100))

        enterInt = textChoice.render("enterInt", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(enterInt, (135, 90))

        if 325+250 > mousePosition[0] > 325 and 50 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 50:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (325, 50, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (325, 50, 250, 100))

        display = textChoice.render("display", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(display, (414, 90))

        if 600+250 > mousePosition[0] > 600 and 50 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 50:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (600, 50, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (600, 50, 250, 100))

        countInt = textChoice.render("countInt", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(countInt, (680, 90))

#########################################################################################
#Middle Row Draw Rects
        if 50+250 > mousePosition[0] > 50 and 250 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 250:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (50, 250, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (50, 250, 250, 100))

        displayReverse = textChoice.render("displayReverse", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(displayReverse, (102, 287))

        if 325+250 > mousePosition[0] > 325 and 250 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 250:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (325, 250, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (325, 250, 250, 100))

        sumInt = textChoice.render("sumInt", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(sumInt, (410, 287))

        if 600+250 > mousePosition[0] > 600 and 250 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 250:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (600, 250, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (600, 250, 250, 100))

        average = textChoice.render("average", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(average, (685, 287))

#########################################################################################
#Middle Bottom Row Draw Rects
        if 50+250 > mousePosition[0] > 50 and 450 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 450:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (50, 450, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (50, 450, 250, 100))

        findMaxORfindMin = textChoice.render("findMax/findMin", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(findMaxORfindMin, (95, 488))

        if 325+250 > mousePosition[0] > 325 and 450 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 450:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (325, 450, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (325, 450, 250, 100))

        search = textChoice.render("search", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(search, (417, 488))

        if 600+250 > mousePosition[0] > 600 and 450 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 450:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (600, 450, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (600, 450, 250, 100))

        writeToText = textChoice.render("writeToText", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(writeToText, (665, 488))

#########################################################################################
#Bottom Row Draw Rects

        if 50+250 > mousePosition[0] > 50 and 640 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 640:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (50, 640, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (50, 640, 250, 100))

        fillFromText = textChoice.render("fillFromText", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(fillFromText, (115, 680))

        if 325+250 > mousePosition[0] > 325 and 640 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 640:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (325, 640, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (325, 640, 250, 100))

        searchReplace = textChoice.render("searchReplace", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(searchReplace, (382, 680))

        if 600+250 > mousePosition[0] > 600 and 640 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 640:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (600, 640, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (600, 640, 250, 100))

        wordCount = textChoice.render("wordCount", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(wordCount, (670, 680))

        pygame.display.update()
#########################################################################################
    eval(selected)

arrayIntro()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop keeps on running indefinitely. In the current code, you detect the mouse click, which then makes the screen go blue but only for an instant and then it proceeds to the next function till it reaches the end and loop continues thereby totally what happened in the last iteration.

Look at the code below. I changed it a little

```
#Import the necessary modules
import pygame
import sys
import os

#Initialize pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the size for the surface (screen)
screenSize = (900,750)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screenSize),0)

# Set the caption for the screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Array")

#Define Colours
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
GRAY = (128, 128, 128)
MAROON = (128, 0, 0)
NAVYBLUE = (0, 0, 128)
OLIVE = (128, 128, 0)
PURPLE = (128, 0, 128)
TEAL = (0,128,128)
PINK = (226,132,164)
MUTEDBLUE = (155,182,203)
PLUM = (221,160,221)

#function here
def selectedFirst():
    runFirst = True

    while runFirst:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
        pygame.display.update()

def arrayIntro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mousePosition = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)

        textChoice = pygame.font.SysFont('americantypewriter', 20)

        mousePosition = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mouseClick = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

#Top Row Draw Rects
        if 50+250 > mousePosition[0] > 50 and 50 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 50:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (50, 50, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (50, 50, 250, 100))

        enterInt = textChoice.render("enterInt", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(enterInt, (135, 90))

        if mouseClick[0] ==1:
            selectedFirst() #change here. Made a new function temporarily to be executed on the click


        if 325+250 > mousePosition[0] > 325 and 50 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 50:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (325, 50, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (325, 50, 250, 100))

        display = textChoice.render("display", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(display, (414, 90))

        if 600+250 > mousePosition[0] > 600 and 50 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 50:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (600, 50, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (600, 50, 250, 100))

        countInt = textChoice.render("countInt", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(countInt, (680, 90))

#Middle Row Draw Rects
        if 50+250 > mousePosition[0] > 50 and 250 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 250:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (50, 250, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (50, 250, 250, 100))

        displayReverse = textChoice.render("displayReverse", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(displayReverse, (102, 287))

        if 325+250 > mousePosition[0] > 325 and 250 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 250:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (325, 250, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (325, 250, 250, 100))

        sumInt = textChoice.render("sumInt", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(sumInt, (410, 287))

        if 600+250 > mousePosition[0] > 600 and 250 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 250:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (600, 250, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (600, 250, 250, 100))

        average = textChoice.render("average", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(average, (685, 287))

#Middle Bottom Row Draw Rects
        if 50+250 > mousePosition[0] > 50 and 450 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 450:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (50, 450, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (50, 450, 250, 100))

        findMaxORfindMin = textChoice.render("findMax/findMin", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(findMaxORfindMin, (95, 488))

        if 325+250 > mousePosition[0] > 325 and 450 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 450:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (325, 450, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (325, 450, 250, 100))

        search = textChoice.render("search", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(search, (417, 488))

        if 600+250 > mousePosition[0] > 600 and 450 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 450:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (600, 450, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (600, 450, 250, 100))

        writeToText = textChoice.render("writeToText", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(writeToText, (665, 488))

#Bottom Row Draw Rects

        if 50+250 > mousePosition[0] > 50 and 640 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 640:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (50, 640, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (50, 640, 250, 100))

        fillFromText = textChoice.render("fillFromText", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(fillFromText, (115, 680))

        if 325+250 > mousePosition[0] > 325 and 640 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 640:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (325, 640, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (325, 640, 250, 100))

        searchReplace = textChoice.render("searchReplace", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(searchReplace, (382, 680))

        if 600+250 > mousePosition[0] > 600 and 640 + 100 > mousePosition[1] > 640:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, (600, 640, 250, 100))
        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, (600, 640, 250, 100))

        wordCount = textChoice.render("wordCount", True, NAVYBLUE)
        screen.blit(wordCount, (670, 680))

        pygame.display.update()

arrayIntro()
```

Its commented where I changed which is..

defined a new func

```
def selectedFirst():
    runFirst = True

    while runFirst:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(MUTEDBLUE)
        pygame.display.update()
```

And called this when clicked

```
        if mouseClick[0] ==1:
            selectedFirst()
```

Try it out.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy7Dk.jpg

EDIT: You don't need to write such a big code. It could be reduced by looping the blitting and mouse tracking in a single func

Comment: Thank you! However, I was wondering what  `eval(selected)` does in the code?

Comment: Also, after I changed my code to incorporate rects, I tried to follow the same logic of the part in which you changed; however it gives me the error: `TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable` , if you were willing to check it out, I've added the new edit of my code above.

Comment: sorry for that eval(selected). Before I posted that code, I used selected = selectedFirst(). and then I call eval(selected) which runs selectedFirst() in the code. I forgot to remove it. What I thought was you can make a list of all callable functions funcList =  [func1, func2, func3...] and when a mouse button is clicked, you can call the corresponding func. Ex. when the third button clicked.. you call eval(funcList[3-1]).

Comment: Your function names are same as that of text surface objects. ex. display() is a function but display is also a surface on which "display" is rendered. So change the name of your functions. It is also the reason why the first function selectedFirst() is working.. because there are no other elements of the same name. P.S. You don't need such lengthy code. You can reduce it by looping